# ReactJS looping through set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I've been strugling with this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Foo = ( props ) => {
    const data = props.data;

    return (
        <div>
            {
                !data ? null : (
                    data.map((item, index) =>
                      <a>{item.name}</a>)
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
};

export default foo;
```

What i pass to Foo is a Set<> of these:

```
public class Bar extends Dto {
    public BigDecimal id;
    public String name;
}
```

Any ideas of what might be the case here?

EDIT:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AnotherFoo extends Component {

  render () {
    const data = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
      <Foo data={data.resultSet} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `!data ? null : (` Why are you negating `data` ? Also you are using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) incorrectly.

Comment: Is `data` an array?

Comment: @NathanP. case it's sometimes null and i get error, that i cannot .map, something in those lines.

Comment: @Simas.B I understand the ternary, but you can write it `data ? (...) : null` this is more _common_

Comment: @jmargolisvt It has multiple values, in my case too. I've tries console.log(data), and i could see that it has multiple values.

Comment: @NathanP. Idk, i just think first way is more readable in this case, at least for me.

Comment: @Simas.B this is surprising at first read :D Also, a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) isn't an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: @NathanP. What's incorrect about how i use "map"?

Comment: Still don't get it :). I'm quite new at JS. Could you elaborate more? :)

Comment: `data.map((index, item) => { ... }` is incorrect since the parameter order is `currentValue, index, array`, so you should write it this way `data.map((item, index) => { ... }`. See the link I provided for more information.

Comment: Can you show the component that you're wiring `Foo` up with?

Comment: @bluetoft I've edited my post, and added that component.

Comment: @NathanP. I've made mistake, by changing item and index places, when writting question. In my program it's in good order. Is there a difference between looping through a Set and through a Array?

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for updating.  what I'm really wondering... is are you sure that data is actually an array at all time.  One thing you can do is ENSURE that it is always an array or Set<T> (TypeScript i'm assuming?) by adding a static default props property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your resultSet is null or undefined at some point.  One thing you can do to add some robustness and clarity is to add propTypes and defaultProps to your component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Foo = ( props ) => {
    const data = props.data;

    return (
        <div>
             {
                !data ? null : (
                    data.map((item, index) =>
                      <a>{item.name}</a>)
                )
             }
        </div>
    );
};

Foo.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string
  })
};

Foo.defaultProps = {
  data: []
};

export default Foo;
```

This will do a couple things.  Give you some warnings when data is the wrong type and or if the items in data are the wrong shape (They should be objects with a name property).  Also... it will give you an empty array if data is undefined.  This should shed some light on your issue.